# i2cdetect detects the device but also shows a full row of addresses

Tags: i2c, pi-zero, pi-zero-w, rtc, ds1307

I have successfully setup a RTC clock ( DS3231 ) on a RPi zero. The whole process was explained [here](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/05/adding-a-ds3231-real-time-clock-to-the-raspberry-pi/). It works as expected but with only a minor difference: Row 5 is filled with numbers from 0x50 to 0x5f. There are guys here who complain about all cells filled, but in this case only a row is fully filled.
What could be wrong here?

UPDATE:
I have not removed the pull-up resistor on the DS3231 board.
Well, here are the photos that may help.

Image 1:

i2cdetect result

[image]

Image2:

my setup
[image]

Image 3:
Soldering
 [image]

Comment: @Behzad Sedighzadeh, Ah let me see.  Usually it means the I2C signal lines SCLK, SDA are bad, noisy and/or distorted for some of the following reasons: (1)  Wires too long, resulting capacitance too large (> 400pF), (2) too many devices on one bus, resulting the pull up resistances too small and overloads the bus (I2C SCL, SDA pins already has 1k8 pull ups on board.  If you add one device, you have module's 4k7 (or 10k) pullup in parallel, one more device one more 4k7, ...  The resultant 1k8 || 4k7 || .. 4k7 becomes very "strong" and Rpi find it too hard to pull it down, .. . / to cont.

Comment: If you have more than a couple of I2C devices on the same bus, you need to remove all except one module the on module pull ups (yes, newbie scarily  desoldering the SMD resistors.). So the resultant pullup is only 1k8 || 4k7, not too strong for the feeble Rpi I2C pins.

Comment: This picture shows an I2C device with pullups removed: https://imgur.com/gallery/xfu1GVY.

Comment: Another i2c device with pullups removed: https://imgur.com/a/vaewSF2

Comment: I found a tutorial on DS3231 pullup removal: https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/05/adding-a-ds3231-real-time-clock-to-the-raspberry-pi/

Comment: @tlfong01 I have only one device on the bus. I forgot to mention that I did not remove the pull-up resistor on the ds3231 board. Can it be the reason?

Comment: @tlfong01, The link I have mentioned is exactly what you have provided.Thanks.

Comment: @Behzad Sedighzadeh, Ah if there is only one DS3231 and no other I2c devices on the bus, then I think it is not necessary to remove the pullup.  There is little chance that only one pullup will matter.  And if you are not that skillful, you might mess up the area around the pullpus.  Another thing is that your i2cdetect shows UU.  There is a slight chance that the driver causes the problem.  One thing you might try is don't use the DS3231 driver in the /boot/config.txt, and see if it helps.

Comment: @Behzad Sedighzadeh, : "The link I have mentioned is exactly what you have provided,". I read the tutorial again, can found it 4 years old.  There is 10% chance that the instructions are out of date, perhaps I can check out later.

Comment: @Behzad Sedighzadeh: IMPORTANT: I remember last time I installed DS3231 on Rpi3B+ stretch, I only edited the /boot/config.txt, and did not edit other "module" config files. Your may like to read this tutorial and see if you also did the things mentioned. :https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=209700. One more thing - you photo shows that you connect another thing on the other socket (possibly for camera, but I forgot).  The camera socket has another I2C bus.  You might like to remove that small guy (does not like camera module, what is it actually?) and see if it helps.

Comment: The mian difference is that the old tutorial edits the /etc/modules fie: "sudo nano /etc/modules, add “rtc-ds1307” to the bottom so it looks something like :
rtc-ds1307" but new tutorial edits the /boot/config.txt file (and add dtoverlay etc).  If you have not edited the /boot/config.txtf file, then there is 50% chance that it is the cause of trouble.

Comment: @joan If I remove just SDA/SCL wires from the board, I get all clear except UU at cell 68.

Comment: @BehzadSedighzadeh Please add that information to your question.

Comment: @Behzad Sedighzadeh, I also guess that the 2015 old tutorial did not use "device tree", causing trouble in new respain versions.  You may like to read my scribbed penzu scratch pad page to get a rough idea: https://penzu.com/p/88262e72.